# Why do I have 2 entries for many names in my OUTLOOK 2003 contacts?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003, contacts

XP SP3

I recently had to have Microsoft Office 2003 re-installed on my computer.

Suddenly I have duplicate contacts, while some contacts that were even more recently added are not accessible through the TO: area of email messages I want to send.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you reinstalled Office, your address book wouldn't have been affected. It sounds like you imported your address book after the reinstallation when you probably didn't need to. Why some of your newer entries are broken I can't say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to clean up your address book by using some kind of [deduper](http://www.supershareware.com/info/deduper.html).